# Prove Grigorchuk group is self similar.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Where I can find a proof of self similarity of Grigorchuk group. I read it somewhere that Grig group follows this interesting property so I read about it but could not find a proof anywhere. It was not so trivial to me, so may be someone has any reference on it which one can provide. Thanks.

Comment: On his personal page ( http://www.math.tamu.edu/~grigorch/papers.htm ) there is, for example, an article "From fractal groups to fractal sets". See, section 4.3.